# My dialer's in-call experience is sideways

Tags: phone-app, orientation

Okay... something really weird that just started happening.
Before getting into the details, my phone is an AT&T Galaxy S3.
I'm running AOKP build `aokp_d2att_jb-mr2_milestone-1`.

The in-call experience, and the "answer call" screen on my phone are "sideways", for lack of a better word. Normally, the in-call experience should look like this:

[image: Screenshot]

However, my in-call suddenly started looking something like the following image:

[image: Screenshot]

I have no idea how it got that way, or how to turn it back. Can anyone tell me how to reset the orientation of the call experience screen?
The same thing happens on my "answer call" screen, but the actual DIALER screen, to place a call, displays normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be solved by clearing the cache and data of the dialler app.

To do this, go to `Settings` › `Apps` › swipe to `All` › select the Dialler application from the list › Clear `Cache` and `Data`.

Comment: Did it! Awesome, thanks. Wish I knew how it got that way... but, least I know how to fix it now.